# Concatenating files from multiple directories with Grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I have a node application where the code is structured by feature in their own directories. I'm using Grunt to concatenate all of these files together. How should I do this without breaking the paths to any dependencies?

Here is an example project structure:

```
index.js
config/
    database.js
    auth.js
feature1/
    routes.js
    functions.js
feature2/
    routes.js
    functions.js
```

Paths are used in `index.js`, e.g `require('./config/database');` so when I concatenate them (e.g. to `dist/scripts.min.js`) I'm getting errors because the `./config/database.js` file doesn't exist. How should I handle this, and is concatenating even the correct approach here?

Answer (score 0):

Folder structure:

```
/MyApp
    /dist
    /src
        /folder1
            file.js
        /folder2
            file.js
    Gruntfile.js
```

Gruntfile.js

```
'use strict'
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt)

    grunt.initConfig({
        concat: {
            options: {
            },
            dist: {
              src: ['src/*/*.js'],
              dest: 'dist/built.js',
            }
        },
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', ["concat"]);

}
```

This will contact all files within all folder inside /src dir, into a single file: /dist/built.js

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue.  When I run `node dist/built.js` I'm getting a "Cannot find module" error because folder1/file1.js imports other modules e.g. `require('../folder2/file.js');` and the path isn't valid from dist/built.js

Comment: could you post full error and share an example of your .js file so i help you out?

Comment: I've put a really simple web app here with just 2 JS files that require each other. https://www.dropbox.com/s/y3hvkfv2ae9e8pg/grunt_so.zip?dl=0 The error is Error: Cannot find module './env'

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the use of grunt-concat.
What it does is, puts together the content of multiple files into one file ('dist/built.js'). It does **not** compile `require("abc")`. In sum, if you change env.js file content to `var env = { port: 8080 };` you can remove `require("env")` from index.js and then **run** built.js

Comment: Okay, so does that mean you can't/shouldn't use concat with projects where you use require?  The env file in this one was just an example.  In reality the files I am requiring are much more complicated which is why I have separated them out.  Seems like a step backwards if I have to go back to having the entire app in one file. And is there a more appropriate Grunt tool to combine files while making sure files with a require don't break?

Comment: Well, i do not see a good use case where you would need to contact files for **back-end app**, having them separated brings you advantages like organization and readability (given that, i have never seen a tool to do it). Now, contact is useful when you need to bring multiple .js files into one to serve the **client(front-end)** code.